# MPI 2D array processing

Tags: c++, mpi

I have 2d array of integers. I want to process it to the new array. Each element of new array is average of primary array element neighbours with given margin. The simple algorithm would be:

```
double *buffer = new double[bufferSize];
for (int row = margin; row < arraySize - margin; row++)
        for (int col = margin; col < arraySize - margin; col++) {
            fillBuffer(row, col, buffer);
            nextData[row][col] = average(buffer);
        }
```

fillBuffer function:

```
void fillBuffer(int row, int col, double *buffer) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = row - margin; i <= row + margin; i++)
        for (int j = col - margin; j <= col + margin; j++)
            buffer[counter++] = data[i][j];
}
```

I want to parrarelize it using MPI. I was wondering if I could use MPI_Scatter function to split primary array for every rank but still every rank will need a data from another rank to calculate values at the edges of array chunk. Maybe I can send primary array to all ranks but how to manage them to process only their part of it? Then how to share calculated elements of array with another rank which needs it to calculate elements at the edges?

As I am new to MPI any tip might be helpful.

Comment: a typical approach is to use ghost cells (sometimes referred as halo), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033222/what-are-ghost-rows-or-columns-in-computation and the link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to let go of the notion that the whole array lives somewhere and then you make the work parallel. You need to create the array in parallel, with each process having only its part. Extrapolate to the future, where each process has a lot of data. Then it is impossible to first create all of that on one process. (And if you don't have a lot of data, then the scatter call will take way more time than just doing stuff on one process.)

So a scatter approach is not the right way.

But if you distribute that array, then processing "only their part" is trivial, because that is all they have! Should they need data from their neighbors, then you need `MPI_Send/recv`.

Comment: So let's say we have a 16x16 matrix and we want to split the work for 2,4,8 etc. processes. Is there a way to make it generic? Or do I have to rely on if statements to `MPI_Send/recv` data to proper ranks?

Comment: @MaciekB If the number of processes divides the number of row, the division of data is simple. If that's not the case you have to balance the work a little. Each process computes `myfirstrow,mylastrow`, allocated `localrows = mylastrow-myfirstrow` rows, and for work iterates `for (myrow=0...localrows)`.